# adding a passed in number to a MySQL cell with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a number to a number already in a MySQL table. I am using POST to pass in the number.

```
    <?php
    require "connection.php";

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
```

Do I have to make 2 separate queries, one to retrieve the current value and set is as a variable and one to insert the new value by adding the number to the variable or can I accomplish this with one query with something like this:

```
    $update_query = "update Table set value = (value + $number) where id like '$id';"
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Trying something fr yourself is a great way of learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update field to add value to existing value:**

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + $number WHERE id = $id;
```

**update field to contact value to existing value:**

*use the CONCAT function :*

```
UPDATE table SET value= CONCAT('$number',value) WHERE id=$id;
```

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS WRONG** `CONCAT()` joins to strings, so `CONCAT(1, 2)` does not returns `3`, but `12`.

Comment: @Justinas please read corectly. in upper line , i said " update field to contact value to existing value" .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use one query `UPDATE tbl_name SET value_col = value_col + :number WHERE id = :id`

---

*Notes*

ID is unique, so you need `id = :id` to achieve faster queries and only update one field.

Use prepared statements instead of putting values directly to query